# Where do the default error pages in ASP.NET Core Web API come from?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm playing around with the `WeatherForcastController` endpoint that the .NET Core Web API template creates.

I've added a bit of middleware to require authentication to access the Swagger pages, as suggested here:

[How to restrict access to swagger/* folder?](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/384#issuecomment-272310182)

```
public class SwaggerAuthorizedMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;        
    public SwaggerAuthorizedMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger")
            && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            //context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            return;
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public static class SwaggerAuthorizeExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerAuthorized(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<SwaggerAuthorizedMiddleware>();
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseSwaggerAuthorized();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My.Api v1"));
    }

[...]
```

And that all seems to work. I haven't wired-up the actual authentication, yet, so when I try to access the page, I get a 401, as I'd expect.

But when I try to access the page from Chrome, I get an error page:

> This page isn’t working
>
> If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
>
> HTTP ERROR 401

And when I try to access the page from Firefox, I get nothing.

Looking at the results in the Chrome developer tools, I see a response with a body containing the messages I see.

Looking at the results in the Firefox developer tools, I see a response with an empty body.

Where is this page coming from? Is it something that the ASP.NET Core Web API is generating? If so, why don't I see it in Firefox?

FWIW, when I change the error to 403, instead of 401, I get a more reasonable error message:

> Access to localhost was denied
>
> You don't have authorization to view this page.
>
> HTTP ERROR 403

But again, only in Chrome.

If I were building a production site, I'd be creating my own custom pages, and none of this would matter. But I'd really like to understand where the defaults are coming from, and I don't.

Comment: Can you try clearing cache and cookies? You might try to hit the site in incognito mode as well.

Comment: What you see isn't generated by ASP.NET Core, but by your browser. If the response has no body, then your browser generates a page based on the response's code.

Comment: Those are just browser's default action to those status codes. Normally browsers expect HTML data with the 200 status code, even on errors.